# Check checkboxes from mysql db

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that submits a checkboxes form to db in the same column from db like "Windows,Android,iOS". And I have a "edit" page that has to show those checkboxes again, but those checkboxes taken from db to be checked. In this case if i have the previous string taken from db i should get like this(bold is checked):

- **Windows**
- OS X
- **Android**
- **iOS**
- Windows Phone

I know how to get an array from the string taken from the db with

```
$devices = "Windows,Android,iOS";
$arrDevices = explode(',', $devices);
```

But I don't know the algorithm to check the corresponding checkboxes in here

```
<input type="checkbox" name="platform" value="Windows">Windows
<input type="checkbox" name="platform" value="OS X">OS X
<input type="checkbox" name="platform" value="Android">Android
<input type="checkbox" name="platform" value="iOS">iOS
<input type="checkbox" name="platform" value="Windows Phone">Windows Phone
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the end of each input (changing the values, of course):

```
<?php print in_array('Windows', $arrDevices) ? 'checked' : '' ?>
```